# Looking for a better way of updating the association of a polymorphic table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a Question and Answer kind of system, such that a question can be voted and answer can be voted. I have a polymorphic voteable association, such that a question and an answer has many votes.
But I want to switch all the votes of an Answer to the Question.
If it was just one association, I could do:

`Answer.first.votes.first.update(voteable: Question.first)`

but this won't work for multiple associations.

I tried to do:

`Answer.first.votes.update_all(voteable: Question.first)`

but it returned an error that it could not find the column `voteable`

I know another way of achieving the same result is to:

`Answer.first.votes.update_all(voteable_type: "Question", voteable_id: 1)`

but I wanted to be sure there's no other way of doing this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's how you have to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do this.
According to the comment from one user:

> I am not sure what are the plans for `update_all`, but **documentation is rather pretty clear that it doesn't work as other relation methods**. It doesn't instantiate objects, it returns only number of updated records, not ActiveRecord::Relation, it simply sends sql straight to the database. Even examples are written more "sql like" than "rails like". The purpose of this method is to do fast update on many records.

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17072